# Binomial probability problem solving

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem

The probability of sales representative making a sale with any one customer is $\frac{1}{3}$ . The sales representative makes eight contacts a day. To find the probability of making four sales, evaluate the term

<sub>8</sub> $C$<sub>4</sub> $( \frac{1}{3} )$<sup>4</sup>$(\frac{2}{4})$<sup>4</sup>

In the expansion $(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3})$ <sup>8</sup>

I know how to evaluate <sub>8</sub> $C$<sub>4</sub> $( \frac{1}{3} )$<sup>4</sup>$(\frac{2}{4})$<sup>4</sup> but I don't understand what they mean by " in the expansion of $(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3})$ <sup>8</sup> "

Comment: that is from one of the terms of the expansion of $(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3})^8$

Comment: It should be $$\binom{8}{4}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^4\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4$$ where $$1 - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$ is the probability of not making a sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binomial theorem is that for variables $a,b$ and positive integer exponent $n$, then we have the following. $$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {}^nC_k a^k b^{n-k}$$

Since $1=(\tfrac 13+\tfrac 23)^8$, then the term for $k=4$ corresponds to the probability of 4 successes and 4 failures among 8 independent trials.

$$1 =\sum_{k=0}^8 \mathsf P(X=k)$$

Therefore.

$$\mathsf P(X=4) ~=~ {}^8C_4\tfrac 13^4\tfrac 23^4$$
That is all.